# Magna/Anime where humanity resets

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

I remember this manga/anime (from around 2017-2020) in which the main characters find a cell phone, which is dated a few years into the future, and they figure out that humanity gets wiped out sometime in the 2000s, then everything repeats, until the next humans are wiped out in the same year, and so on. Can anybody help me find this?

Comment: Basically the plot of the Matrix sequels

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you see/read this?

Comment: What is humanity wiped out by in the story?

Comment: @LogicDictates I believe its a natural disaster of some sort iirc

Answer (score 2):

[image: Cover of manga Noah's Notes volume 1]

This sounds very similar to Haruto Ikezawa's short-lived 2018 manga *Noah's Notes*.

User johnknight648 on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/noahsnotes/comments/97q1bc/haruto_ikezawa_noahs_notes_is_cancelled/) describes it:

> The manga Noah's notes is about a determined archaeologist named Noah Umberbach and his assistant who is also a student and is dragged by him on his journey named Mirai Kotobuki as they try to uncover the secrets of our world while trying to prevent itself from repeating the cycle of apocalypse.

[Tvtropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/NoahsNotes) (cursory warning) confirms the recurring apocalypse element:

> Humanity has been destroyed 10000 years ago in an unexplained catastrophe. This is mankind's "second round" on Earth, making the exact same decisions all over again and leading up to the same catastrophe anew. Noah theorizes that there may have been more rounds before.

It ran in *Weekly Shonen Jump* for 25 chapters, which were collected in three volumes.